# How to access a Python object attribute in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to access an object attribute variable in Robot Framework tests and then validate the values of these attributes.

I have the following Python class:

```
class TestingClass(object):


    def __init__(self, client_id=None, redirect_uri=None, state=None):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.uri = uri
        self.state = state



    def url_authorize(self):
        self.oauthsession = OAuth2Session(client_id=self.client_id, uri=self.uri, state=self.state)
        self.authorize_endpoint_url = self.oauthsession.authorization_url(
            url="http://localhost:8080/authorize")[0]
        return self.authorize_endpoint_url


    def authorize(self):
        request = requests.get("http://localhost:8080")
        self.status_code = request.status_code
        self.content = request.content
        self.json = request.json
```

I want to be able to grab any one of the attributes created in the Authorize (authorize method) and validate it. So I want to do something like this:

```
* Variables
${CLIENT_ID}                        to
${URI}                              http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback
${STATE}                            random

* Settings
Documentation                       Tests Suite
Library                             Utilities.TestingClass         ${CLIENT_ID}       ${URI}
...                                                                           ${STATE}       

*Keywords

*Test Cases
Authorize Test 1
    [Documentation]                 Test that the user is redirected to the authorize 
    ...                             endpoint
    ...                             when accessing the OAuth Client
    Url Authorize
    Authorize
    
    Should Be Equal As Integers     Utilities.TestingClass.status_code     200
```

However this gives: `Utilities.TestingClass.status_code != 200` which is no surprise to me.

How do I grab this attribute to compare it? Would I need to maybe return all the attributes made from the `authroize()` method in a list/dictionary/some sort of array and then access by indexing? Or is there a more straight forward way to do this with Robot Framework?

Comment: I think instead of reinventing the wheel have a look at this  - https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following two choices, both will involve the usage of [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax). I would prefer the second option.

1. You can use the [Get Library Instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance) keyword, to get the library instance in the test. The you can access its member variables using the extended variable syntax. Here is an example based on your code, I just replaced the return values with constants.

   ```py
   class TestingClass(object):

       def __init__(self, client_id=None, redirect_uri=None, state=None):
           self.client_id = client_id
           self.uri = redirect_uri
           self.state = state

       def url_authorize(self):
           self.oauthsession = None
           self.authorize_endpoint_url = "http://localhost:8080/authorize"
           return self.authorize_endpoint_url

       def authorize(self):
           self.status_code = 200
           self.content = 'content'
           self.json = { "A" : ["StringA1",  "StringA2"], "B": ["StringB1","StringB2"]}
   ```

   ---

   ```py
   *** Settings ***
   Library    Utilities.TestingClass    to    http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback    random

   *** Test Cases ***
   Test
       Url Authorize
       Authorize
       ${TestingClass}=    Get Library Instance    Utilities.TestingClass
       Log    ${TestingClass.status_code}
       Log    ${TestingClass.content}
       Log    ${TestingClass.json}
   ```
2. The other option is to modify the `authorize` method, so it will return what `requests.get("http://localhost:8080")` returns. Then you could access the status code, content and JSON in the same way as above, using the extended variable syntax.

   ```py
   class DummyRequestReturnValue():
       def __init__(self):
           self.status_code = 200
           self.content = 'content'
           self.json = { "A" : ["StringA1",  "StringA2"], "B": ["StringB1","StringB2"]}


   class TestingClass(object):

       def __init__(self, client_id=None, redirect_uri=None, state=None):
           self.client_id = client_id
           self.uri = redirect_uri
           self.state = state

       def url_authorize(self):
           self.oauthsession = None
           self.authorize_endpoint_url = "http://localhost:8080/authorize"
           return self.authorize_endpoint_url

       def authorize(self):
           request = DummyRequestReturnValue() 
           return request
   ```

   ---

   ```py
   *** Settings ***
   Library    Utilities.TestingClass    to    http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback    random

   *** Test Cases ***
   Test
       Url Authorize
       ${response}=    Authorize
       Log    ${response.status_code}
       Log    ${response.content}
       Log    ${response.json}
   ```